# How to integrate Payumoney payment gateway using backend- Aspnetcore and Frontend - React js? Kindly help me

Tags: c#, reactjs, aspnetcore-environment

How to integrate Payumoney payment gateway using backend- Aspnetcore and Frontend - React js? Kindly help me

```
    [HttpPost("onlinePayment")]
    [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]

    public void onlinePayment()
    {

        string merchantKey = "*******";
            string salt = "*******";
            byte[] hash;
             Random rnd = new Random();
             string hex = "";
            string text = hex + rnd.ToString() + DateTime.Now;


        byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

        UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] hashValue;
        SHA512Managed hashString = new SHA512Managed();
        
        hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(message);
        foreach (byte x in hashValue)
        {
            hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
        }

               
                string strHash = hex;
               string txnid1 = strHash.ToString().Substring(0, 20);
        string d = merchantKey+"|"+ txnid1+"|"+ 1000 + "|" + "TestInfo" + "|" + "Dhana" + "|" + "dhana@gmail.com"+"|||||"+ salt;
        var datab = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(d);
        using (SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed())
        {
            hash = shaM.ComputeHash(datab);
        }

        Response.Redirect("https://test.payu.in/_payment");
       Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        return;
        }
```

This is backend code i am trying to integrate with js..It is correct way to integrate or not?
Or give me some code examples.

Comment: Do you mind being a little more specific in your question? I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for. Are you saying you have the onlinePayment ASPNetCore API working and you don't know how to call the API from JavaScript? I'm not sure if this would help. https://medium.com/@mayankgupta1338/node-js-express-js-payumoney-payment-integration-32d3058c714 though it's not ASPNetCore.

Comment: @tlbignerd in this documentation, They are using node and express js....Is any document or blogs available for react js?